# Delete featured image with post Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Iv'e been searching for a while now and my search so far has been very unsuccessful. I'm looking for a function that deletes the featured image and post when clicking delete post on the posts page in the dashboard.

What I would like: Clicking delete on a post deletes instantly along with it's featured image instead of being moved to the "trash".

Sorry I'm not a pro developer, I'm a noob and just starting out. Any help would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In any case, wp_delete_attachment requires attachment_id and not post_id. saved you half an hour ;)

```
add_action( 'wp_trash_post', 'delete_post_permanently' );

function delete_post_permanently( $post_id ){    
    wp_delete_post($post_id, true); // deletes post
    //wp_delete_attachment ( $post_id, true ); // deletes attachment
    if( has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) )
    {
        $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
        wp_delete_attachment($attachment_id, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use add_action hook into delete_post function, and run a function that will deelte the featred image after getting it by the post id.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post

Comment: Actually correct action would be `before_delete_post`.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the Wordpress function for "before deleting a post"...

So under your theme's function.php file:

```
function delete_associated_media($id) {
// check if page
if ('page' !== get_post_type($id)) return;

$media = get_children(array(
    'post_parent' => $id,
    'post_type' => 'attachment'
));
if (empty($media)) return;

foreach ($media as $file) {
    // pick what you want to do
    wp_delete_attachment($file->ID);
    unlink(get_attached_file($file->ID));
}
}
add_action('before_delete_post', 'delete_associated_media');
```

This will delete all the attachments (images) on that page being removed. You will have to tweak it just to be the featured image instead, however it might help you figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `wp_trash_post` action hook, it runs onn post, page, or custom post type is about to be trashed

```
add_action( 'wp_trash_post', 'delete_post_permanently' );

function delete_post_permanently( $post_id ){    
    wp_delete_post($post_id, true); // deletes post
    wp_delete_attachment ( $post_id, true ); // deletes attachment
}
```

Comment: This works partially. When clicking delete, It deletes automatically the post which is great but the featured image is still not deleting unfortunately.

Comment: This part "wp_delete_attachment ( $post_id, true );" requires $attachment_id and not $post_id!!!!